# Problema al llenar una tabla con AJAX. (Object > d:null) ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, asp.net, datatables

Tengo un problema al querer cargar una tabla en ASP.NET usando AJAX. El tema es que cargo una lista desde un WebMethod y la retorna bien pero el asunto es que en la consola del navegador no llega el array. Me dice lo siguiente:" > Object > d:null"

Este es el WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static object CargarGrilla(int aciertos, string apellido, string DNI, string premios)
    {
        List<Ganador> lista = new List<Ganador>();
        lista.Add(new Ganador { Aciertos = aciertos, Apellidos = apellido, Dni = DNI, Premios = premios });
        object json = new { data = lista };
        return json;
    }
```

Y este es el codigo JS:

````
function dtUsers() {  
    var table = $("#table-users").DataTable({  
        destroy: true,  
        responsive: true,
        ajax: {
            method: "post",
            url: "Sorteo.aspx/CargarGrilla",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: function (d) {
                return JSON.stringify(d);
            },
            dataSrc: "d.data"
        },
        columns: [
            { "data": "Aciertos" },
            { "data": "Apellidos" },
            { "data": "Dni" },
            { "data": "Premios" }
        ]
    });
}```
````

Comment: si únicamente dejas en dataSrc como data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te recomiendo lo siguiente:

1. Da un vistazo al API de los Datatables, en especial, en la sección de AJAX.
   https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax
2. La respuesta desde tu Web Method debe tener la estructura que marca en el API.
   Yo, en mis datatables, siempre utilizo el mismo formato.

```
{ 
    "data" : [
                 { "index1" : "value1" },
                 { "index2" : "value2" },
                 { "index3" : "value3" },
             ] 
}
```

3. Puedes verificar en la consola que la respuesta este siendo de esta manera.
4. El **dataSrc** en la definición de tu Datatable, sirve para indicar el index del cual tomará los datos de la respuesta del AJAX, siendo por defecto "data" se puede omitir.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta